# make NodeJS function synchronus? sends json response before querying database

Tags: java, android, node.js, rest, express

I am making a login/register android app UI with nodejs as the backend language. Whats happening is that whenever I click the register button, it sends the json response before querying the database (select statement to check if username exists) causing the android app to get the wrong response which causes me to click the button twice to register the correct response. For instance lets say their is a username called test in the database and I try to sign up using the username test, it will tell me that the username is already taken and if erase test and enter lets say 'bob' which does not exist in the database it still says the username is already taken even though it is not but when I click the register button again it will register the user. I am assuming this is happening because it is async(it sends the json response while or before querying the database). How can I make this synchronus or is there another way to fix this?

server file:

```
var express = require('express');
var app  = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mysql = require('mysql');

//connection
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "password",
    database : "androidtest"
});

//use json
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

//declare variables to hold values entered by the user
var name;
var username;
var password;
var age;

//boolean array to let frontend know what is going on
var response;

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    //retrieve variables
    username = req.body.username;
    name = req.body.name;
    age = req.body.age;
    password = req.body.password;

    //query database
    //check if username is taken
    var select = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1";
    con.query(select, [username], function (err, results) {
        if (err) throw err;
        //if username is taken send json string 'exists' to android app
        if(results.length) {
            response = {"exists" : "true"};     
        //if username is available send string 'success' and add the user to the database
        } else {
            var add = "INSERT INTO users (name, username, age, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
            response = {"success" : "true"};
            con.query(add, [name, username, age, password]);
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('row inserted');
        }
    });
    //send json
    res.json(response);
    //prevents the functions from being executed more than once
    res.end('/');
});
//listen on port 3000
app.listen(3000);
```

android app java:

```
bRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        final String name = etName.getText().toString();
        final String username = etUserName.getText().toString();
        final String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
        final int age = Integer.parseInt(etAge.getText().toString());

        Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                    //Boolean exists = jsonResponse.getBoolean("exists");
                    String exists = jsonResponse.getString("exists");
                    if (exists.matches("true")) {
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "username already exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        toast.show();
                    }
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                    //Boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                    String success = jsonResponse.getString("success");
                    if (success.matches("true")) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                        RegisterActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                    } else {
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                        builder.setMessage("Register Failed")
                                .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                .create()
                                .show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(name, username, age, password, responseListener);
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(RegisterActivity.this);
        queue.add(registerRequest);
    }
});
```

}

Comment: There are several hundreds posts like this here.  Put the `res.json(...)` inside the database callback so it triggers only when you actually have the data.  And, there's no need for `res.end()` after `res.json()`.

Comment: that actually worked, I tried that before asking the question but I was using console.log to display the retrieved variable and they were being displayed more than once and they were also being added to the database more than once so I added the res.end() which  caused to display and be added to the database only once. Now however, I am not using console.log() and it does not seem like they are being added to the database more than once

Comment: has my answer helped you? does it work now?

Comment: yes it wrks now

Answer (score 0):

You have to put

```
res.json(...);
res.end('/');
```

after the closing bracker of the following line (after & outside the else block):

```
console.log('row inserted');
```

then it first gets executed when to query has finished.